# How to tackle this exercise about Ito's formula?

Tags: itos-lemma

In the following exercise, I can't get started on question 2) as I am not sure what to do when there is an integral inside:

[image: ito-example]

Could you help me out?

Comment: Could you state what you tried and at which step exactly you are in trouble? As a hint: exercise 1 in combination with itos lemma should help

Comment: @muffin1974 as he's stuck with the integral, I guess he doesn't know where to start so I can understand why he wrote the question this way. But providing the hint is really good.

Answer (score 6):

Let
\begin{align*}
X_t = W(t)W_*(t) - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\big(W_*(u)^2+ W(u)^2\big)du.
\end{align*}
Then, 
\begin{align*}
dX_t &= W(t) dW_*(t) + W_*(t) dW(t) -\frac{1}{2}\left(W_*(t)^2+ W(t)^2\right)dt,
\end{align*}
as $W$ and $W_*$ are independent. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
X_t = \int_0^t \big[W(s) dW_*(s) + W_*(s) dW(s)\big] -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\left(W_*(s)^2+ W(s)^2\right)ds.
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
\langle X, X\rangle_t = \int_0^t\left(W_*(s)^2+ W(s)^2\right)ds.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
d\langle X, X\rangle_t &= \left(W_*(t)^2+ W(t)^2\right)dt.
\end{align*}
Since $R_2(t) = e^{X_t}$, 
\begin{align*}
dR_2(t) &= e^{X_t} dX_t + \frac{1}{2}e^{X_t}d\langle X, X\rangle_t\\
&= R_2(t)\Big( W(t) dW_*(t) + W_*(t) dW(t) \Big).
\end{align*}

Comment: You'll need to comment what you do at each step if you want to help him understand the solution.

Comment: @Gordon can you just explain how did you get <dXt,dXt>

Comment: @Lior, I added more details.

Comment: @Lior, a more heuristic way to compute $\langle dX_t,dX_t\rangle$ is to note that $dW(t)dW(t)=dt$, $dW(t)dt=0$, and $dW(t)dW_∗(t)=0$ (because of independence) etc..